# Python: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'

Tags: python

Got small issue, just modified my python module to match the new html template, but it is giving me an error if I use  , in the old module is working fine can you point me what I have to do in order to use the new module and update my website template.

Comment: Don't build up complex HTML in Python like that. It's error prone and impossible to read. There are several template languages available: you should use one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're matching a different regex:

```
html_post_start = re.search('<div class="articleline2"></div>', html)
```

vs

```
html_post_start = re.search('<div class="excerpt"></div>', html)
```

One matches, the other doesn't (returning `None`).

Comment: Thank you so much that's it, how to change it with mutable ? Edit: I rather change the new template css, so "excerpt" will become "articleline2". Thank you again for the help, love you - no homo